# Xamarin - Sql Lite database creation causes crash on some phones

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin, path

My app makes use of a SQLlite database. On the simulator and on 2 phoes I tested it on, the path is something like this:

`/data/user/0/com.companyname.galshare/files/galleries.db3`

on another phone, where the app keeps crashing, the path is like this:

`/mnt/expand/52382cff-205f-40b0-89ab-967c917cb9aa/user/0/com.companyname.galshaer/files/galleries.db3`

The phone is a Xiaomi Mi A3. OS Android One 9.0 and the app is automatically installed on the SD card.

the code to generate the path for the db3 file is this:

```
        string fileName = "galleries.db3";
        string folderPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        string completePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, fileName);
```

The error message is:

`Could not open database file: /mnt/expand/52382cff-......  ..../galleries.db3 (CannotOpen)`

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: According to your description, you means that you have this error message on Xiaomi Mi A3? I don't have Xiaomi Mi A3, but I test your code on Google Pixel device, I get the path like the first path you provided, and don't have any issue.

Comment: By setting the application to install on the internal memory, it works... Xiaomi Mi A3 decides where to install the app.. if it gets installed on the external memory then it does not work.. I changed the setting in the project settigns to "internal only" and it works, but its not the real solution.. just a workaraound..

Comment: It seems that you have one solution now, please give one reply about your solution and mark your reply as answer, it may be helpful to other community members who face the same issue, thanks.

Comment: this is not a solution.. its a workaround.. I am still looking for a solution